# Mysql bulk UPDATE from specific ID/row to ID/row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this one:

```
ID  address  note
1    addr1   day1
2    addr2   day1
3    addr3   day1
4    addr4   day1
5    addr5   day1
6    addr6  
7    addr7   
8    addr8   
9    addr9   
10   addr10
```

How can I use UPDATE to bulk add the value "day2" to the column "note" for the rows from 6 to 10?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do:

```
update t
    set note = 'day2'
    where id between 6 and 10;
```

However, you might want:

```
update t
    set note = 'day2'
    where note is null;
```